# Loading a custom service as a dependency of my Angular module throws an "uncaught object" exception in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

### The relevant code:

```
var app = angular.module('client', [
     'ngRoute'
    ,'controllers'
    //,'proxyServices'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
   function($routeProvider){
         $routeProvider
             .when('/launch', {
                  templateUrl: 'partials/launch.html'
                 , controller: 'LaunchCtrl'
             })
             .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/launch'
             });
         }
]);
```

Note that I have proxyServices commented out. The launch page displays all fine and dandy.
Whenever I try to register it with my module, I end up getting the "uncaught object error" out of angular.js when angular attempts to load my 'client' module.

Here's my service...it's just a stub that does nothing right now; trying to minimize moving parts under my current test and ran into this stumbling block.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('proxyServices',[])
    .factory('fooService', function() {
        var serviceCall = function(){
          return true;
        }
        return 
        {
            events: function() { return serviceCall(); }
        };
});
```

### What did I do wrong?

> ### Edit:
>
> Well, I looked into the error from angular.js Line 78 and found this:
>
> > "[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either
> >     misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
> >     module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
> >     argument.
>
> What's that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Stupid error on my part.

I was trying to do too much under a single test and it took putting a breakpoint on line 78 of angular.js and **decoding the error coming in** *rather than the message logging to the console* to figure it out.

I put proxyServices in a new file; *just before lunch*.

I didn't register that new file as a script source in my parent html page.

As I said, stupid error.  But the error that actually shows is very cryptic and had my attention diverted to the syntax of my service.